# Easiest way to monitor New Relic APDEX in realtime

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

We're scaling our servers based on APDEX value, and for now I'm polling for it every X minutes.

I'd like to know if there is a way to get APDEX value when it CHANGES through WebHooks. From what I read in docs, I can get WebHooks notification only whenever there is an alert or deployment, but what I'm looking for is to get a notification whenever APDEX value changes.

Thank you in advance
 - Jack

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support for notifications based on APDEX changes not directly related to an alert or deployment. However since you're polling for the APDEX value already, you can easily keep track of the previous value and take action when it changes.

That said, please be aware that the APDEX value can fluctuate slightly on each poll cycle, so you should take this into account when deciding when and if to take action.